# Using Twilio, Heroku Scheduler and Node to send Scheduled Text Messages - nothing happening

Tags: node.js, heroku, twilio, scheduler

Have a node project deployed on heroku.  Using the Heroku Scheduler some scheduling code seems to run but the Twilio SMS call does nothing.  This code works outside of the scheduler.

This is the scheduler.js code that is run from Heroku Scheduler:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

var config = require('../config');
var client = require('twilio')(config.accountSid, config.authToken);

function sayHello() {
  console.log('Helloxxxx');
  sendSms('+13476979750', 'from Scheduler');
  console.log('goodbye-xxxx');
}
sayHello();
process.exit();

function sendSms(to, message) {
  client.messages.create({
    body: message,
    to: to,
    from: config.sendingNumber
  }, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.error('Could not send message');
      console.error(err);
    } else {
      console.error('SMS');
    }
  });
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I believe Yoni's answer is correct in that you are exiting the process before the HTTP request to the Twilio API completes. However, while promises are cool, I don't think you need all that extra code just to make this work. Instead you could just exit the process once you receive the callback.

Try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

var config = require('../config');
var client = require('twilio')(config.accountSid, config.authToken);

function sayHello() {
  console.log('Helloxxxx');
  sendSms('+13476979750', 'from Scheduler');
  console.log('goodbye-xxxx');
}
sayHello();

function sendSms(to, message) {
  client.messages.create({
    body: message,
    to: to,
    from: config.sendingNumber
  }, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.error('Could not send message');
      console.error(err);
    } else {
      console.error('SMS');
    }
    process.exit();
  });
};
```

Comment: Yup, philnash's answer is simpler and better.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me you may be missing some async processing logic, so that your one-off dyno scheduled by Heroku scheduler is exiting (via process.exit()) before sayHello() has a chance to complete.

Try promisifying your code, with something like this (using the [q library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/q)):

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

var config = require('../config');
var client = require('twilio')(config.accountSid, config.authToken);
var Q = require('q');

function sayHello() {
   console.log('Helloxxxx');
   return sendSms('+13476979750', 'from Scheduler')
       .then(function(){
            return console.log('goodbye-xxxx');
       })  
}


function sendSms(to, message) {
    var deferred = Q.defer();
    client.messages.create({
         body: message,
         to: to,
         from: config.sendingNumber
    }, function(err, data) {
       if (err) {
           console.error('Could not send message');
           console.error(err);
           deferred.reject(err);
       } else {
           console.log('SMS');
           deferred.resolve();
       }
    });
    return deferred.promise();
};

sayHello()
    .then(function(){
        console.log('Exiting...')
        process.exit();
});
```